# SmallIcon Color Turn To White Automatically Why In Notification Android?

Tags: android

```
public void animatedNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(ic)
            .setLights(Color.GREEN, 10000, 10000)
            .setWhen(when)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText("Plants Need Watering Some of Your work is pending");

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.setSmallIcon(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.mipmap.ic_launcher : R.drawable.notification_icon_bw_xhdpi)
.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.primary, getTheme()))
```

Use color to distinguish your app from others. Notification icons should only be a white-on-transparent background image. (https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

Before Android Lollipop you can use same `mipmap` icon for all notification icon. But from Lollipop onwards you need to create new notification icon (Silhoette kind of icon).

Comment: You need to create seperate icon for notifications which will be rendered well on white background.

Comment: i create it before we code the app on Eclipse but now we move on Android Studio here the problem Arise,..

Comment: This is not problem with your IDE. Its specific to android version.

Comment: Observe any notifications that appear on your phone(if it lollypop or above). They are shouloette type of icons which are rendered on a white transparent background.

Comment: But Why the facebook icon is coloured??

Comment: @HUSNAINSARWAR If you use a colored icon on a Android 4 device, it's going to be colored as expected. If you use ANY icon on Android 5 device all color is going to be replaced with white (or whatever the system needs). You need to work with transparency in your notification icons.

Answer (score 1):

Small icon appears white because of Material theme used for your app [notification](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html).

Comment: So Which theme i use ??